# How to delete scattered points from a data set

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, noise-reduction

I have the coordinates of  the cloud of points stored in a matrix. Few of the points are isolated from the others. Does anybody know how I can delete them?  The points are shown in the picture. I would appreciate if you could help me because I am not a mathematics guy :(
Since I am a new user I could not upload the picture however the points at the bottom show the data set with 4 scattered points that I want to delete.

```
 .......
 ........
  .........
  .........         .
  ..........       ..
  ......            .
  .....
  ...
```

Comment: I think you can plot the points as a graphics and then delete them using a method at [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/interactively-extract-points-from-a-plot-listplot-or-smoothdensityhistogram) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20066/how-to-interactively-select-points-inside-certain-region-in-a-plot).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code hope will help for you:

```
data = Table[{Random[], Random[]}, {100}];

DynamicModule[{p = {0.5, 0.5}, linePts = {}, p1 = {0., 0.}, 
  pts = data}, 
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Dynamic[Point[pts]], Locator[Dynamic[p]], 
    Line[Dynamic[If[p != p1, AppendTo[linePts, p]; p1 = p]; 
      linePts]]}], 
  Row[{Button["updata", 
     pts = Select[pts, ! Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[linePts, #] &]], 
    Button["copy points", Print[Flatten[Position[data, #] & /@ pts]]],
     Button["Reset", linePts = {}; pts = data;]}]]]
```

You can draw a region in the plot and then delete them in the plot. "update" button will show the remain points, "copy points" will copy the remain points position, "reset" will reset to the original plot.

[image]